# Rails 3 - MP3 files in public folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mp3, download

I added mp3 files to the /public folder and I found a bit issue.

In my view I added the links:

```
= link_to "Interview 1", "/interview_01.mp3"
```

When I see the link from the page, everything appears normal until I click on it. The browser hangs on for a minute or more, the tile changes to "undefined" and my Google Chrome freezes.

What's wrong with it? How can I make it so people can just download the file?

Comment: Place mp3's in the "public/audios" directory and generate the link via `<%= audio_tag "name_of_file.mp3" %>`. For more information check out [asset tag helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers)

Comment: Hey Alen, it works for IE, Chrome but not for Firefox. Is it because of file type issue? Firefox cannot play mp3?

Answer (score 5):

### Edit: More context for my answer since someone down voted me

When you link to an mp3 file, most modern browsers will attempt to play that file directly in the browser. Your browser is likely freezing because whatever plugin your browser is using to begin playing the file is broken. My guess would be you are running windows and it is attempting to use a quicktime plugin or something along those lines.

If you don't want the browser to play the file and you actually want the file to begin downloading, you need to add a few extra headers to the HTTP response. The most important being:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filenamehere.mp3"`

My original answer provides instructions for accomplishing this. If this is not what you were hoping to achieve then you can disregard it.

If you want the file embedded directly into the page with the new HTML5 audio tag, you can follow the advice given in the comment to your question by @Alen.

### Original answer:

You should try sending the file from a controller action using the `#send_file` controller helper method.

```
= link_to "Inteview 1", :controller => 'files', :action => 'send_file', :filename => 'interview_01.mp3'
```

Then

```
class FilesController

  def send_file
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/#{params[:filename]}"
    send_file file_path, :filename => params[:filename], :disposition => 'attachment'
  end

end
```

Reference Rails Api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

The `send_file` method sets the HTTP headers correctly to tell the browser to download the file instead of attempting to render it.

Comment: Why do you need a controller to serve files out of the `public` dir?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you need the controller to set the HTTP headers to tell the browser to start a download of the file instead of attempting to open it. I don't know about your browser, but If I hit an MP3 file directly with mine it begins to play it. I would have to right click on the link he showed in his example and then click "Save As" to actually download it. My understanding of the question was that he wants the file to actually be downloaded, not handled by the default action for that extension by the browser.

Comment: As for his freezing issue, I would guess that whatever plugin his browser is using to start to play that MP3 is busted. Maybe I should have been more explicit about this in my answer. I also should have mentioned that I wouldn't store the files in the `public` directory typically when using the method I outlined.

Comment: @RyanBigg: Are you the one that down voted my answer? If so, could you please up vote based on my response to your comment. Unless of course I am missing something here.

Comment: I'm using Mac and running the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Did you try out my suggestion for forcing the file to start downloading?